# Unable to load ebpf program loading stops at [13] FUNC bpf_prog1 type_id=9 Invalid arg#1 why is that? or what is this error even means

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ebpf

This is my ebpf program

```
#include <linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <linux/types.h>

#define __TRACE_COMMON_H
#define SYSCALL(SYS) "__x64_" __stringify(SYS)



struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") my_map = {
      .type        = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
      .key_size    = sizeof(int),
      .value_size  = sizeof(int),
      .max_entries = 42,
      .map_flags   = 0
};



SEC("kprobe/sys_write")
int bpf_prog1(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    struct S {
        int pid;
        int cookie;
    } data;

    data.pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    data.cookie = 99;

    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &my_map, 0, &data, sizeof(data));

    return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
int _version SEC("version") = 190;
```

And I am trying to compile ebpf program and load it like following

root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/kern# clang -g -target bpf -c trace_output_kern.c -o trace_output_kern.o

but when I run it it throws error that

```
root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/kern# ./trace_output_user a
libbpf: Error loading BTF: Invalid argument(22)
libbpf: magic: 0xeb9f
version: 1
flags: 0x0
hdr_len: 24
type_off: 0
type_len: 900
str_off: 900
str_len: 600
btf_total_size: 1524
[1] PTR (anon) type_id=3
[2] INT int size=4 bits_offset=0 nr_bits=32 encoding=SIGNED
[3] ARRAY (anon) type_id=2 index_type_id=4 nr_elems=4
[4] INT __ARRAY_SIZE_TYPE__ size=4 bits_offset=0 nr_bits=32 encoding=(none)
[5] PTR (anon) type_id=6
[6] ARRAY (anon) type_id=2 index_type_id=4 nr_elems=2
[7] STRUCT (anon) size=32 vlen=4
    type type_id=1 bits_offset=0
    key_size type_id=1 bits_offse
    key_size type_id=1 bits_offset=64
    value_size type_id=1 bits_offset=128
    max_entries type_id=5 bits_offset=192
[8] VAR my_map type_id=7 linkage=1
[9] FUNC_PROTO (anon) return=2 args=(10 (anon))
[10] PTR (anon) type_id=11
[11] STRUCT pt_regs size=168 vlen=21
    r15 type_id=12 bits_offset=0
    r14 type_id=12 bits_offset=64
    r13 type_id=12 bits_offset=128
    r12 type_id=12 bits_offset=192
    rbp type_id=12 bits_offset=256
    rbx type_id=12 bits_offset=320
    r11 type_id=12 bits_offset=384
    r10 type_id=12 bits_offset=448
    r9 type_id=12 bits_offset=512
    r8 type_id=12 bits_offset=576
    rax type_id=12 bits_offset=640
    rcx type_id=12 bits_offset=704
    rdx type_id=12 bits_offset=768
    rsi type_id=12 bits_offset=832
    rdi type_id=12 bits_offset=896
    orig_rax type_id=12 bits_offset=960
    rip type_id=12 bits_offset=1024
    cs type_id=12 bits_offset=1088
    eflags type_id=12 bits_offset=1152
    rsp type_id=12 bits_offset=1216
    ss type_id=12 bits_offset=1280
[12] INT long unsigned int size=8 bits_offset=0 nr_bits=64 encoding=(none)
[13] FUNC bpf_prog1 type_id=9
[14] PTR (anon) type_id=15
[15] FUNC_PROTO (anon) return=16 args=(void)
[16] TYPEDEF __u64 type_id=17
[17] INT long long unsigned int size=8 bits_offset=0 nr_bits=64 encoding=(none)
[18] VAR bpf_get_current_pid_tgid type_id=14 linkage=0
[19] PTR (anon) type_id=20
[20] FUNC_PROTO (anon) return=21 args=(22 (anon), 22 (anon), 16 (anon), 22 (anon), 16 (anon))
[21] INT long int size=8 bits_offset=0 nr_bits=64 encoding=SIGNED
[22] PTR (anon) type_id=0
[23] VAR bpf_perf_event_output type_id=19 linkage=0
[24] INT char size=1 bits_offset=0 nr_bits=8 encoding=SIGNED
[25] ARRAY (anon) type_id=24 index_type_id=4 nr_elems=4
[26] VAR _license type_id=25 linkage=1
[27] TYPEDEF uint32_t type_id=28
[28] TYPEDEF __u32 type_id=29
[29] INT unsigned int size=4 bits_offset=0 nr_bits=32 encoding=(none)
[30] VAR _version type_id=27 linkage=1
[31] DATASEC .data size=16 vlen=2
     type_id=18 offset=0 size=8
     type_id=23 offset=8 size=8
[32] DATASEC .maps size=32 vlen=1
     type_id=8 offset=0 size=32
[33] DATASEC license size=4 vlen=1
     type_id=26 offset=0 size=4
[34] DATASEC version size=4 vlen=1
     type_id=30 offset=0 size=4
[13] FUNC bpf_prog1 type_id=9 Invalid arg#1

libbpf: Error loading .BTF into kernel: -22. BTF is optional, ignoring.
libbpf: load bpf program failed: Invalid argument
libbpf: -- BEGIN DUMP LOG ---
libbpf: 
unknown opcode 8d
processed 0 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0

libbpf: -- END LOG --
libbpf: failed to load program 'bpf_prog1'
libbpf: failed to load object './trace_output_kern.o'
ERROR: loading BPF object file failed
```

**Update**

and this is my trace_output_user.c

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <bpf/libbpf.h>


//create .o file root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/kern# clang -I /lib/modules/5.14.1/build -I /usr/include/bpf/ -O2 -Wall -c trace_output_user.c

static __u64 time_get_ns(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    return ts.tv_sec * 1000000000ull + ts.tv_nsec;
}

static __u64 start_time;
static __u64 cnt;

#define MAX_CNT 100000ll

static void print_bpf_output(void *ctx, int cpu, void *data, __u32 size)
{
    struct {
        int pid;
        int cookie;
    } *e = data;

    if (e->cookie != 0x12345678) {
        printf("BUG pid %llx cookie %llx sized %d\n",
               e->pid, e->cookie, size);
        return;
    }

    cnt++;

    if (cnt == MAX_CNT) {
        printf("recv %lld events per sec\n",
               MAX_CNT * 1000000000ll / (time_get_ns() - start_time));
        return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct perf_buffer_opts pb_opts = {};
    struct bpf_link *link = NULL;
    struct bpf_program *prog;
    struct perf_buffer *pb;
    struct bpf_object *obj;
    int map_fd, ret = 0;
    char filename[256];
    FILE *f;

    //snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "..o", argv[0]);
    obj = bpf_object__open_file("./trace_output_kern.o", NULL);
    if (libbpf_get_error(obj)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: opening BPF object file failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* load BPF program */
    if (bpf_object__load(obj)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: loading BPF object file failed\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    map_fd = bpf_object__find_map_fd_by_name(obj, "my_map");
    if (map_fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: finding a map in obj file failed\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    prog = bpf_object__find_program_by_name(obj, "bpf_prog1");
    if (libbpf_get_error(prog)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: finding a prog in obj file failed\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    link = bpf_program__attach(prog);
    if (libbpf_get_error(link)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: bpf_program__attach failed\n");
        link = NULL;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    pb_opts.sample_cb = print_bpf_output;
    pb = perf_buffer__new(map_fd, 8, &pb_opts);
    ret = libbpf_get_error(pb);
    if (ret) {
        printf("failed to setup perf_buffer: %d\n", ret);
        return 1;
    }

    f = popen("taskset 1 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null", "r");
    (void) f;

    start_time = time_get_ns();
    while ((ret = perf_buffer__poll(pb, 1000)) >= 0 && cnt < MAX_CNT) {
    }
    kill(0, SIGINT);

cleanup:
    bpf_link__destroy(link);
    bpf_object__close(obj);
    return ret;
}
```

llvm-objdump output

```
trace_output_kern.o:    file format elf64-bpf


Disassembly of section kprobe/sys_write:

0000000000000000 <bpf_prog1>:
; {
       0:   7b 1a f8 ff 00 00 00 00 *(u64 *)(r10 - 8) = r1
;     data.pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
       1:   18 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 r1 = 0 ll
       3:   79 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 r1 = *(u64 *)(r1 + 0)
       4:   8d 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 callx r1
       5:   7b 0a e8 ff 00 00 00 00 *(u64 *)(r10 - 24) = r0
       6:   b7 01 00 00 78 56 34 12 r1 = 305419896
;     data.cookie = 0x12345678;
       7:   7b 1a f0 ff 00 00 00 00 *(u64 *)(r10 - 16) = r1
;     bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &my_map, 0, &data, sizeof(data));
       8:   18 01 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 r1 = 8 ll
      10:   79 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 r0 = *(u64 *)(r1 + 0)
      11:   79 a1 f8 ff 00 00 00 00 r1 = *(u64 *)(r10 - 8)
      12:   18 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 r2 = 0 ll
      14:   b7 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 r3 = 0
      15:   7b 3a e0 ff 00 00 00 00 *(u64 *)(r10 - 32) = r3
      16:   bf a4 00 00 00 00 00 00 r4 = r10
;     data.pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
      17:   07 04 00 00 e8 ff ff ff r4 += -24
      18:   b7 05 00 00 10 00 00 00 r5 = 16
;     bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &my_map, 0, &data, sizeof(data));
      19:   8d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 callx r0
;     return 0;
      20:   79 a0 e0 ff 00 00 00 00 r0 = *(u64 *)(r10 - 32)
      21:   95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 exit
root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/kern# ^C
root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/kern# ^C
```

Comment: Can you please share the source code of `trace_output_user`?

Comment: @pchaigno I have updated my question with trace_output_user.c program. please check

Comment: `unknown opcode 8d` -> it looks like there's something wrong with the program that libbpf tries to load. Do you get something consistent with `llvm-objdump -S trace_output_kern.o`?

Comment: @Qeole  yes it shows correctly

Comment: @Qeole I have also posted the output of `llvm-objdump -S trace_output_kern.o`

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with the helper calls, but I'm not sure why they don't translate as expected. Maybe @pchaigno knows? Can you please give your LLVM and kernel versions?

Comment: @Qeole llvm version `12.0.0` kernel 5.14.1

Comment: @Qeole are u sure this is how to create .o file for ebpf program `clang -g -target bpf -c trace_output_kern.c -o trace_output_kern.o`?

Comment: Found it, you need to pass  `-O2` when you compile your BPF program (`trace_output_kern.c`)

Comment: @Qeole yes now it does not throw that error but now it kind of not able to find sys_write function new error `libbpf: kprobe perf_event_open() failed: No such file or directory
libbpf: prog 'bpf_prog1': failed to create kprobe 'sys_write' perf event: No such file or directory
ERROR: bpf_program__attach failed`

Comment: is it possible I did not included debug flags in compiling kernel

Comment: The function you want to attach to is probably not named `sys_write`. More likely `__x64_sys_write`? `SEC("kprobe/" SYSCALL(sys_write))`

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, and the solution is as follows，Add the compile option -O2 and use LLVM_STRIP

```
$(Q)$(CLANG) -g -O2 -target bpf -D__TARGET_ARCH_$(ARCH) $(INCLUDES) $(CLANG_BPF_SYS_INCLUDES) -c $(filter %.bpf.c,$^) -o $@
$(Q)$(LLVM_STRIP) -g $@ # strip useless DWARF info
```